# Style of lines in raw gnuplot and pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, gnuplot

I am drawing a function using raw gnuplot in pgfplots and I am not able to make the lines thicker and to change the colour (for instance grey).

My example is the following:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xmin=-2,xmax=2,ymin=-2,ymax=2]
        \draw plot[id=curve,raw gnuplot] function{
            f(x,y) = (y**2 + x**2) - 0.5;
            set xrange [-1:1];
            set yrange [-1:1];
            set view 0,0;
            set isosample 1000,1000;
            set cont base;
            set cntrparam levels discrete 0; 
            unset surface;
            splot f(x,y)
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Even though in the example I am showing a circumference I would like to use raw gnuplot since for some examples the function may become also an ellipse.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you tried, but line styles are set using the normal `pgfplots`/TikZ options, e.g. `\addplot [blue, ultra thick, raw gnuplot] ...`. (I think it makes more sense to use `\addplot` than `\draw plot`, since it's inside an `axis`.)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
         xmin=-2,xmax=2,
         ymin=-2,ymax=2
         ]

    \addplot [ % <-- changed
         gray, thick, % <-- added
        id=curve,raw gnuplot
        ]
           function{
            f(x,y) = (y**2 + x**2) - 0.5;
            set xrange [-1:1];
            set yrange [-1:1];
            set view 0,0;
            set isosample 1000,1000;
            set cont base;
            set cntrparam levels discrete 0; 
            unset surface;
            splot f(x,y)
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```